# Несколько выборок в регулярном выражении

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Допустим есть текст

```
> Test test test.
1 - [Contact id]
2 - [full name]
3 - [address]
4 - [appartment id|custom text] some text
5 - [cars] text...
```

Мне нужно с помощью регулярного выражения найти все внутри квадратный скобок и дальше идет 2 условия, если внутри этих квадратных скобок нет символа "|", тогда выбрать нужно весь текст, если есть этот символ, тогда нужно в одну группу выбрать весь текст что идет до этого символа, во вторую группу все что идет после(в пределах квадратных скобок).

С помощью этого выражения `/\[([^|]+?)\]/g` Получается делать выборку внутри скобок, если нет символа `|`, но сделать выборку отдельно того и того не получается

Comment: вы как то пытались решить свою проблему самостоятельно?

Comment: дополнил вопрос, написал на чем сейчас остановился

Comment: нашел что должно работать выражение `/\[(.+?(?=\|))\]/`, но не находит вообще ничего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данное регулярное выражение - то, что вам нужно:

```
\[([^|\[\]]+)\|?(.*?)\]
```

Или так:

```
\[([^\[\]|]+)\|?([^\[\]|]*)\]
```

Или так:

```
\[(?|(?:([^\]\[]+)\|([^\]\[]+))|([^\]\[]+))\]
```

[Тут](https://regexr.com/46s3p) можно посмотреть в живую (2ой вариант)

Стоит отметить, что значения (все до `|`, все после `|` или все в принципе), хранятся в группах (1), (2), (1) соответсвенно

Comment: Спасибо, на сайте все отлично работает, но почему-то при выполнении кода  пропускается первая найденная закрывающая квадратная скобка и доходит до последней.
мой код `preg_replace_callback('/\[(?|(?:(.+)\|(.+))|(.+))\]/',
            function ($matches) {
                //some code
                return $result;
            }, $text);`

Comment: Проблема в том что у меня в одной строке весь текст из-за это выражение немного не подходит

Comment: @hehoboy можно так `\[(?|(?:([^\]\[]+)\|([^\]\[]+))|([^\]\[]+))\]`, но это костыль, конечно

Comment: @hehoboy `\[([^\[\]|]+)\|?([^\[\]|]*)\]` или так. Отпишитесь когда попробуете

Comment: отлично отрабатывают и первый и второй вариант, как я понимаю второй вариант предпочтительней? Спасибо большое!

Comment: @hehoboy да второй он поменьше. Хотя и его можно оптимизировать.

Comment: @hehoboy еще вот так `\[([^|\[\]]+)\|?(.*?)\]`

Comment: @wcobalt, как вариант `\[(.+?)(?:\|([^]]+))?]`

Comment: @Let'ssayPie гляжу я вашу статистику, и не могу понять, как вы умудрились накрутить сперва 2К репутации, а после бана ещё докрутить несколько сотен? ( O^о )

Comment: @Эдуард, у вас ко мне какие-то претензии имеется?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie вы всегда на вопросы отвечаете вопросами? ) Если да, то следующий ответ писать не утруждайтесь.